# Change Component Margin with VueJS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, responsive, tailwind-css

I have a very basic VueJS sidebar component. I am also using [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/).

I have a navigation component with a button. The button is clicked an emits an event called "toggle" triggering the 'toggle' method on my sidebar.

My sidebar is *closed* on mobile and *open* on desktop using TailwindCSS responsive utilities.

Within my sidebar component, I'd like to be able to open/close (set the margin/flex-grow/shrink) the sidebar depending on its current state. I could use VueJS and bind classes to set these attributes but it would never work for both as one is defaulted open and the other closed - How would I know to set margin or remove it?

Below is my very basic component. Please excuse the formatting I couldn't get the last brace to format correctly.

```
<template>
<div class="w-76 -ml-76 lg:ml-auto lg:flex-grow lg:max-w-xs bg-red">
    <slot></slot>
</div>
```

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
        toggled: false
    }
},

methods: {
    toggle() {
        // 
    }
},

mounted() {
    this.$parent.$on('toggle', this.toggle)
}
}
```

How can I achieve this?

[image: Desktop view with sidebar shown][image: Mobile with hidden sidebar]